# If cookie does not exist alert and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if a cookie exists when the user lands on a page and if the cookie does not exist I need to popup an alert and then redirect to another page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if( $.cookie('cookiename') == null ) { 
    alert("OH NOES U NO HAS COOKIE");
    window.location.replace('http://url');
}
```

Comment: `location` is a property of `window`, not `document`.

Comment: thanks, you apparently commented that while i was in the edit window fixing it ;)

Comment: Yes I did :3 We sniped each other, I think.

Answer (score 8):

```
if( document.cookie.indexOf("cookiename=") < 0) {
    alert("Cookie not found, redirecting you.");
    location.href = "newpage.html";
}
```

Be careful not to use a cookie name that may be the end of another cookie name. If this is likely, you'll need to do a full cookie read, or use PHP instead.

Comment: you'll probably want to use replace() rather than href, to keep the current page out of the session history (i.e. not get stuck in a loop when trying to use the browser's 'back' button) -- also as he's requesting jquery he can get around the "end of a cookie name" issue

Answer (score 1):

Using `Javascript` `ReadCookie()` Function

`ReadCookie()`, you realize immediately, is used to read a cookie.

You can read any cookies,  provided they are being read on the same domain they were set at.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var acookie = ReadCookie("cookiename");
if(acookie.length == 0)
 { 
  //redirect somewhere 
 }
</script>
```