# How can I redirect to a different URL if they have never visited the site before

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to know how could I redirect users to a different URL/Subdomain if they have never been on the website before.

So if you have never been to "example.com" then you would be redirected to "welcome.example.com".

I am not sure if you can do this using the .htaccess file but I do not know much about htaccess. My site is HTML.

Thank you.

Comment: Um, if they haven't been there before you won't have any tracking information on them...that's how you'll know they haven't been there before and should send them to your welcome page...

Comment: Using "tracking information" isn't what I am looking at, maybe something to do with cookies or htaccess. Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: I think you completely missed my point

Comment: Please explain more about what you mean and how I could do this, thanks.

Comment: the "welcome" feature, is commonly done by setting a cookie

Comment: Okay thank you for your reply, how would I do this using cookies?

Comment: Well, basically each visitor is given a cookie by you. That means you can redirect them depending on whether they already have a cookie from some previous visit or not. How to set a cookie is explained in many tutorials and also in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, looking around on other similar questions on StackOverflow and I am not really getting anywhere. I have made a cookie by this JS code: `document.cookie = "newuser=no";` then the redirect code if the cookie does not exist: `if( $.cookie('newuser') == null ) { 
    window.location.replace('https://welcome.connor-burton.co.uk');
}`

Which nothing has worked.

Comment: I found this here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145187/if-cookie-does-not-exist-alert-and-redirect]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some javascript to set one cookie with some exipiration time. Then when user access the site you need to verify if cookie is defined and redirect the user to the correct page. Try with this code inside a `<script></script>` in your **index.html**

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (getCookie('isPageAccessed') == "") {
    setCookie('isPageAccessed', true, 7);
    window.location.replace("welcome.example.com");
  }
};

function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, expirationDays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expirationDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cookieName) {
    var name = cookieName + "=",
        ca   = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, nothing seems to happy though? Am I meant to have made a cookie or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, was way too simple haha.

```
document.cookie = "page=visited;";
if(!document.cookie.includes('page=visited;')) {
window.location.href = "https://example.com";
}
```